# How to create a date timer

Tags: java, date, countdowntimer

I am creating a countdown timer, I have 2 dates(now and end date) in format mm:dd:yyyy:hour:minute:sec and I need to show how much time is remaining, effectively that is
 end date:time - current date:time

I thought of converting both dates in milliseconds, subtracting and then converting them back to dates but that seems too much of a hassle
How to implement this effectively in java?

Comment: Well. As a matter of fact, `java.util.Date` is little more than a wrapper around a long that represents milliseconds. Also maybe something from Joda Time may be of interest to you.

Comment: Something like [PrettyTime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) might be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the `joda-time` framework do it for you

```
String date = "02:13:2013:14:45:42"; // one of these is your end time
String date2 = "02:13:2013:14:45:49"; // the other gets smaller every time as you approach the end time
// 7 seconds difference

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM:dd:yyyy:HH:mm:ss"); // your pattern

DateTime dateTime = format.parseDateTime(date);
System.out.println(dateTime);

DateTime dateTime2 = format.parseDateTime(date2);
System.out.println(dateTime2);

Duration duration = new Duration(dateTime, dateTime2);
System.out.println(duration.getMillis());
```

Prints

```
2013-02-13T14:45:42.000-05:00
2013-02-13T14:45:49.000-05:00
7000
```

So you parse your date Strings into `DateTime` objects and use the `Duration` object to calculate the time difference in some time unit.

You can alternatively use an `Interval` or `Period` object (depending on the precision required)

```
System.out.println(duration.toPeriod().get(DurationFieldType.seconds()));
```

---

You state

> I thought of converting both dates in milliseconds, subtracting and
>   then converting them back to dates

Why would you have to convert them back? You already have them. You're just interested in the time between.

Comment: I am converting them back to dates because in my application I want to display the time remaining, in the date format

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal Note that an duration is not a date, so it makes no sense to display it in the `hour:minute:seconds...` format you do with dates. The `Period` objects has the `get` method which you can use with any time unit. You can show hours, minutes, and seconds left, for example.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It does, actually, make sense to want to display the result in h:m:s format, for example, if you have a count down timer. But you are right, the OP should be using the getter methods of the Duration to build the String output ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Right, in a timer format it makes sense, but not in a date format with a timezone for example.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar until = Calendar.getInstance();

until.set("YYYY","DD","HH","MM","SS");

getTimeDifference(until);

---

```
private String getTimeDifference(Calendar until) {
    Calendar nowCal = (Calendar) until.clone();
    nowCal.clear();
    Date nowDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    nowCal.setTime(nowDate);
    int sec = until.get(Calendar.SECOND) - nowCal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    int min = until.get(Calendar.MINUTE) - nowCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hrs = until.get(Calendar.HOUR) - nowCal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

    String timeDiff = hrs+":"+min+":"+sec;

    return timeDiff;
}
```

Comment: Date/time difference is a complicated process, needing to take into account a number of variable factors (not including daylight savings ;)), the further the two dates are apart, the worse the problem becomes. Subtracting the milliseconds from each other isn't going to result in highly accurate result. Better to use a dedicate library, such as JodaTime- IMHO